# Discount cart item price excluding a category and its children in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, taxonomy-terms

The fact is that the customer asks for a 50% discount for "Local Pickup" - I have already done this (I found a code here on StackOverFlow that applies a discount on all goods), but there is one more condition - this discount should not be applied to two categories goods.
[Sorry for Russian image;)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7Ftj.png)

I tried to go through each product in the list of orders, and check whether it belongs to a certain category or not through various operators (is_category, in_category, has_term), but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?
(id = 37 is the id of the Premium rolls category)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_cart_item_price', 10, 1 );
function custom_cart_item_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;
    
    $category_id = 37; // premium-rolls id
    $cats = hml_get_category_gender_line( $category_id );
    
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if (!has_term($cats, 'product_cat', $value['product_id'] )){
            $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price(); // Get the product price
            $new_price = $price-$price*50/100; // the calculation
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $new_price ); // Set the new price
        }
        
    }
}

function hml_get_category_gender_line( $cat_parent ){
    // get_term_children() accepts integer ID only
    $line = get_term_children( (int) $cat_parent, 'product_cat');
    $line[] = $cat_parent;

    return $line;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

There are some mistakes in your code. The code below will apply a discounted price on cart items from specific product category *(and its children)*:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_cart_item_price', 10, 1 );
function custom_cart_item_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;
    
    $parent_id = 37; // premium-rolls id
    $taxonomy  = 'product_cat';
    
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $terms_ids  = get_term_children( $parent_id, $taxonomy, $product_id ); // get children terms ids array
        array_unshift( $terms_ids, $parent_id );  // insert parent term id to children terms ids array
        
        if ( ! has_term( $terms_ids, $taxonomy, $product_id ) ){
            $new_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price() / 2; // Get 50% of the initial product price
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $new_price ); // Set the new price
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Thank you a lot!) You are a genius!;)

Comment: Could you help me match your code with this?

[link](https://psv4.userapi.com/c856416/u164125235/docs/d16/f3c91a9c2427/local_pickup.txt?extra=zv0E8jP0hV71RIq_wxPw_PJiac04jZY4NqM6ZSzL1pAzyGGftilUicRtNuPgoEO0d03LOMzBgfcyx-k1T8paVY6d67ACrT_dkh-rg22vM1rNonvKN6uTlF_InB0XuKInHItLgXndqllGxHDA51KOe-6V-A&dl=1)

Comment: @KirillNikonov It should be better to ask a new question, providing all related code and details…

Comment: How to setup this code to work only when client select "local pickup" as Shipping method?

Comment: @ViktorG see this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849601/combine-discounted-shipping-cost-with-discounted-cart-items-prices-in-woocommerc